# stripe - embedded iframe height is off, cutting off zip code

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm exploring using stripe and have started by using the "payments" layout w/the v3 javascript.  Problem is the "zip code" is always getting cut off as it looks like the iframe height is not adjusting properly.  Any suggestions as to what i may be doing wrong or how to adjust the iframe?
html:

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="payment-form">
<div class="form-row">
    <div id="card-element"> <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. --> </div>
    <!-- Used to display Element errors -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
</div>
```

js (angular/ionic):

```
this.card = this.stripeElements.create('payment');
this.card.mount('#card-element');
```

screenshot
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set height in the element that wrapped the card element?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am experiencing it too using Ionic React

Comment: Was anyone able to solve this issue? Its 2023 and I'm still running into this.

Comment: Oddly, i think it was a Chrome issue.  Testing on a real device or simulator does not show the issue.  And now, i can't get it to happen in Chrome any longer either.  Sorry, not much help.